# Filter rows according non-continuous range of values in a particular column

Tags: r, dataframe

So far this does the job for a continuous range, filtering out the rows not in that range.
`df[df$position %in% 5061518:5061520,]`

How do I do the same for non-continuous range such as:

5061518:5061520 and 5061522:5061525 and 5061540:5061550

Comment: wrap in `c()` - df[df$position %in% c(5061518:5061520, 5061522:5061525, 5061540:5061550),]`